# Base64 to PDF in PHP - Getting corrupted file

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to use PHP to generate a PDF from a Base64 string.
The base64 is working when I paste it in a browser, or use the site base64.guru, however everytime it writes locally and when I try to open it, it says it is corrupted.

The Base64 string is

```
$text = 'data:application/pdf;base64,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';
```

This is what I try to use.  It writes the file to the folder, but it says it is corrupted.  I have tried all different solutions on stack overflow and can't seem to make it work.

```
$data = sanitize_text_field(base64_encode($text));
file_put_contents('output.pdf', base64_decode($data));
```

Comment: What you have there is a base64 rendition of the file, plus some data: URL prefix, and you're encoding it a second time as base64. Neither of which makes it a valid PDF file.

Comment: @mario I've tried to only decode it, but without any success as well.  Not sure how the guys at https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf are able to make it work, I just copy/paste the exact string of mine above.

Comment: try to remove "data:application/pdf;base64,"

Comment: @AndreaManzi That was it, my goodness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to remove "data:application/pdf;base64,"